# Repeat Control - Tabindex

Tags: xpages

I use Repeat Controls to register data. Based on some tests, I want the cursor to move to different fields. When I set a tabindex for a field in a Repeat Control, the tab order changes. The cursor now moves through all the fields in the column with the lowest tabindex and after that all the fields in the next column.
Is there a way to change the tab order so that the cursor moves "row"-wise? If I have to programmaticly mananage the cursor movements, what is the easiest way to get the cursor position in the Repeat Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Domino 8.5.3, you can create a tabindex custom attribute and use the indexVar to prefix the tabindex so that you get row by row tabbing. Custom attributes can be created under all properties - attrs.

I think you have to use a custom attribute as the standard attribute can only be calculated on page load, and it looks like indexVar isn't available on page load.

E.g.

```
<xp:inputText>
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="tabindex" value="#{javascript:return rowIndex + '1';}" />
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will be best off with a client side script. Use dojo.query to get all the fields and then sort them out.